# Calculate the totale value of grouped by rows in angular Infragistics Ui grid

Tags: angular, typescript, infragistics, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I'm using angular Infragistics UI grid in typescript 12

And I'm trying to calculate the totale of the price field when the grid is in group by mode.
Say I have 2 groups by client, group 1 contained 2 items and group 2 contained 3 items.
I have to get the total price by each grouped client (for example 300 for group1 and 800 for the second).

Here is my code in HTML component

```
<igx-grid #grid id="grid" [data]="listeinvoices" [groupingExpressions]='expr' [allowFiltering]="true"  [autoGenerate]="false" height="500px">

  <igx-column  field="client" header="client" [groupable]="true"></igx-column>
  <igx-column  field="price" header="price" [groupable]="true"></igx-column>

  <igx-column  field="invoicenumber" header="invoice nb" [groupable]="true"></igx-column>
</igx-grid>
```

The code of ts component :

```
export class FactureComponent implements OnInit {

public expr: ISortingExpression[];

  @ViewChild("grid") public grid!: IgxGridComponent;


  constructor(private rest: RestService,private toastr: ToastrService,private excelExportService: IgxExcelExporterService) 
  {
    this.expr = [
      { dir: SortingDirection.Asc, fieldName: 'client', ignoreCase: false,
        strategy: DefaultSortingStrategy.instance() },
      
      ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In that case you can use the [Group Row template](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/groupby#group-row-templates) and structure it as you wish. Check out the [documentation](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/groupby#group-row-templates), I believe you will find it helpful:

```html
<ng-template igxGroupByRow let-groupRow>
    <div>
        <span>
        {{ groupRow.expression.fieldName }}:
        </span>
        <span>{{ isDate(groupRow.value) ? formatDate(groupRow.value) : groupRow.value }}</span>
        <igx-badge [value]="groupRow.records.length"></igx-badge>
        <span> Ordered in 2017:</span><span>{{ calc2017(groupRow.records)}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

```
public calc2017(values: any[]) {
   const startDate = new Date('1/1/2017');
   const endDate = new Date('12/31/2017');

   return values.filter((x) => x.OrderDate >= startDate && x.OrderDate <= endDate).length;
}
```

You can define your own Row Selector template as well

```html
<ng-template igxGroupByRowSelector let-groupByRowContext>
    {{ groupByRowContext.selectedCount }} / {{ groupByRowContext.totalCount  }}
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Summaries with the GroupBy feature. Now that you've set `groupable` to the columns that you want to group, just go ahead and set `[hasSummary]="true"` to the `Price` column.

This will show you all Summary information for the Price column - like count, min, max, sum and avg. In your case you want to show only Total (sum), so my suggestion would be to create a custom summary:

```
class TotalSummary {

    public operate(data?: any[]): IgxSummaryResult[] {
        const result = [];
        result.push({
            key: 'sum',
            label: 'Total',
            summaryResult: IgxNumberSummaryOperand.sum(data)
        });
        return result;
    }
}


public totalSummary = TotalSummary;
```

Template:

```html
<igx-column field="Price" header="Price" dataType="number" [groupable]="true" [hasSummary]="true" [summaries]="totalSummary">
```

Further more, if you want to show the Summaries only on childLeve (within the grouped level) you can use the [summaryCalculationMode](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html#summarycalculationmode)

For more information, check out the section of [Summaries with GroupBy](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/summaries#summaries-with-group-by) and [Custom Grid Summaries](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/summaries#custom-grid-summaries)

Comment: i tried this and it worked perfectly ! thanks a lot , but what if i want to display the total label next to group by header which means i wanna have for example : ( clients: anna(3) Totale :400)